Semi-invariants of $\mathrm{GL}(V)\curvearrowright\mathbb{C}\big[\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)\otimes V\big]$?
There is an action $\mathrm{GL}(V)\curvearrowright\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)\otimes V$ for any vector space $V$. We view $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)\otimes V$ as an affine space $\mathbb{A}^N$. Consider the action $\mathrm{GL}(V)\curvearrowright \mathbb{A}^N$, we say $f\in\mathbb{C}[\mathbb{A}^N]$ is semi-invariant of order $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ if
$$f(g.x)=\det(g)^kf(x),\quad\forall\;x\in\mathbb{A}^N,\;g\in\mathrm{GL}(V). $$
I wonder if there exist non-constant semi-invariant functions for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$?

There are many such invariants.
This is a way to construct one for every value of $\dim V$.
An element $T \in \mathrm{Sym}^2 V \otimes V$ can be regarded as a $V$-valued element of $\mathrm{Sym}^2 V$, that is a symmetric matrix whose entries are linear forms on $V^*$.
Let $F_T$ be the determinant of this matrix. Then $F_T$ is a polynomial of degree $\dim V$ on $V^*$ whose coefficients are themselves polynomials in the coefficients of $T$ (this is a covariant of order and degree equal to $
\dim V$). The discriminant of $F_T$ is a polynomial only depending on the coefficients of $T$.
It has very large degree, and it is a semi-invariant, or equivalently an invariant for the induced action of $\mathrm{SL}(V)$. When $\dim V = 2$, this discriminant is the restriction to $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V) \otimes V$ of the Cayley hyperdeterminant on $V \otimes V \otimes V$.
This is just an example. There are many such semi-invariants. In fact, the Hilbert polynomial of the ring of semi-invariants has degree roughly equal to $\dim (\mathrm{Sym}^2 V \otimes V) - \dim \mathrm{GL}(V)$. Very little is understood about the actual generators, except that there are usually a lot of them.
